# Lameduck meaning as verb

Tags: meaning

Let me draw your attention to a [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/176511/48962) posted in English Language Learners where
OP has extracted a text from the book "The Collector" by John Fowles that uses the verb **lameduck**. I can not find any reference to such verb online.

> Violence and force are wrong. If I use violence I descend to his
>   level. It means that I have no real belief in the power of reason, and
>   sympathy and humanity. That I **lameduck** people only because it flatters
>   me, not because I believe they need my sympathy. I’ve been thinking
>   back to Ladymont, to people I **lameducked** there. Sally Margison. I
>   **lameducked** her just to show the Vestal Virgins that I was cleverer
>   than they. That I could get her to do things for me that she wouldn’t
>   do for them. Donald and Piers (because I’ve **lameducked** him in a sense,
>   too) — but they’re both attractive young men. There were probably
>   hundreds of other people who needed **lameducking**, my sympathy, far more
>   than those two. And anyway, most girls would have jumped at the chance
>   of **lameducking** them.

Have any of you got the original book? Does it contain that exact text? In affirmative case, what does that verb mean?

Comment: So, what is the definition of "lame duck"?

Comment: @HotLicks "a person or thing that is disabled or ineffectual"

Comment: @RubioRic https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.usage.english/19kUEDNKNIU and https://books.google.pt/books?id=zUkdBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=the+collector+james+fowles+lameduck&source=bl&ots=a3d90nvq7Z&sig=RCWwnIl9kPD9tpUJ0rlm1HlcSZM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsxvyq8PPcAhURqxoKHTL2CY4Q6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=lameduck&f=false

Comment: @AndyT, no I believe it's actually used like that. It appears in these two theses about Fowler's writing http://knowledgecommons.lakeheadu.ca:7070/bitstream/handle/2453/2431/BorichP1993m-1b.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y in this case it's hyphenated and https://theses.cz/id/yrm2p2/EXISTENTIALISM_IN_THE_WORKS_OF_JOHN__FOWLES.pdf not hyphenated

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2014/aug/05/johnfowles review of the book on the guardian

Comment: @bookmanu Thanks for the links. I've edited my question accordingly, removing the OCR/typo guess.

Comment: Any noun can generally be "verbed" to mean the action form to the noun. **To lameduck** would just be to  "act as a lameduck," "be a lameduck."

Comment: @Kris So "to lameduck" is "faking to be a lame duck so one can get others attention and help?

Comment: @Kris Or "treating someone as a lame duck who needs help"? It's not clear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a reference to lameduck and the John Fowles' book The Collector in [Something and Nothingness: The Fiction of John Updike & John Fowles By John Neary](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_9k_R1uNoz0C&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=fowles%20lameduck&source=bl&ots=XEP4f8fAdS&sig=mc69Lj9AOOoqC5-kfeGDJWk1UH8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPjpT99_PcAhXCy4UKHQjDD1IQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=fowles%20lameduck&f=false)

See last four lines.

[image: The Collector]

Perhaps Fowles used artistic licence with his character Miranda?

[Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/idiom/lame-duck/) defines lameduck as:

> A lame duck is a politician who has been voted out of office but whose term is not yet up, or a politician who is still in office but cannot run for reelection.
>
> Lame duck as applied to a politician is a North American term, though it is gaining usage across the globe.
>
> The first American president referred to as a lame duck was Calvin Coolidge.
>
> The phrase lame duck may also be used to describe an ineffectual person.
>
> Lame duck originated on the London Stock Market in the 1700s to describe an investor who is unable to cover his debts, the plural form is lame ducks.
>
> Lame duck is spelled with a hyphen as in lame-duck when used as an adjective before a noun about half the time.

[Merriam-Webster's](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/lame%20duck) second definition for the word is:

> chiefly British : a person, company, etc., that is weak or unsuccessful and needs help

In the story Miranda Grey is kept captive by the protagonist Frederick Clegg. He is from a lower social class than Miranda, perhaps lameducking is the act of putting someone down in the context of the quote in OPs question?

A contributor to [New Casebook Series:John Fowles edited by James Acheson](https://books.google.pt/books?id=iL29CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT81&lpg=PT81&dq=lameducking&source=bl&ots=fUpfHcXxuo&sig=wz5aW081SJHucTKWeOr1WxTkvyw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj08KnzlfTcAhWhxYUKHe0kDLg4FBDoATAGegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=lameducking&f=false) seems to confirm this interpretation

[image: The Collector 2]

[From this essay on the book](http://www.cathywhite.co.uk/2014/09/12/essay-on-the-collector-by-john-fowles/)

> He admits that he made a mistake setting his sights on Miranda as she was of a higher social class than he: “… she’s only an ordinary common shop-girl, but that was my mistake before, aiming too high” (Fowles 282) and so if he were to have a new guest, it would be someone who would respect him and who would learn from him, instead of the other way round as it was between Frederick and Miranda: “I ought to have got someone who would respect me more. Someone ordinary I could teach” (Fowles 282). This is a conclusion he comes to after he has read Miranda’s diary and finds out that she never really loved him and felt superior to him.

and [this analysis](https://przegladdziennikarski.pl/analysis-of-the-collector-by-john-fowles/)

> Miranda feels sorry for him, but at the same time, she has the feeling that she should not

[Here](https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2014/aug/05/johnfowles) is the Guardian book review of The Collector and [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/243705.The_Collector) & [Dutch Readers'](https://www.scholieren.com/boekverslag/71930) takes on the book

Comment: Presumably the more directly annotative meaning is ‘treat or perceive as a lame duck’. Perceiving and treating someone as weak, ineffectual, and in need of help would be more or less tantamount to being condescending towards them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet what about including your comment as an answer? Great work, bookmanu!

Comment: @RubioRic Nah, bookmanu did all the work; I’d never even heard of _lameduck_ as a verb. They’re free to incorporate my comment into their own answer if they want. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Lameducking is Cockney rhyming slang for ‘f*cking’. (See [Cockney Rhyming Slang as a Disguise Mechanism for the Prevalent English Swear Words](https://www.academia.edu/25513164/Cockney_Rhyming_Slang_as_a_Disguise_Mechanism_for_the_Prevalent_English_Swear_Words).)

Miranda, in the book, could be talking about all the people  she has slept with. Although in some of the contexts in which she uses the term this doesn’t seem to make sense.

Comment: I added a link to back up the rhyming slang, but I think that it needs to be supported from the text (which seems unlikely, especially if you say it doesn't make sense in all contexts).